# Assigned Variable in Kotlin Doesn't Resolve Correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, java.util.scanner, ibeacon

I have an issue where `var instance: IbeaconTooth? = null` is highlighted with "Do not place Android context classes in static fields". I tried everything I can think of to resolve this issue but nothing seems to work. Whenever I run the app, the error I receive is "ibeantooth is null , please use init() method". Any assistance is appreciated.

IbeaconTooth.kt

```
class IbeaconTooth constructor(mContext: Context) {

        private val cxt: Context = mContext
        private val manager: BluetoothManager = cxt.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        private val adapter: BluetoothAdapter = manager.adapter
        private var scanner: BluetoothLeScanner? = null
        private var isScan: Boolean = false
        private val TAG = "beacon"
        // scan callback
        private var bleCallback: BeaconBleCallback? = null
        private var leCallback: BeaconLeCallback? = null

        init {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                scanner = adapter.bluetoothLeScanner
            }
        }

        companion object {

            var instance: IbeaconTooth? = null

            fun init(context: Context) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    synchronized(IbeaconTooth::class.java) {
                        if (instance == null) {
                            instance = IbeaconTooth(context)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            fun getIbeacon(): IbeaconTooth {
                if (instance == null) {
                    throw IllegalArgumentException("ibeantooth is null , please use init() method")
                }
                return instance as IbeaconTooth
            }

        }

        fun startBeacon(onBeaconScanListener: OnBeaconScanListener) {
            if (isScan) {
                Log.d(TAG, "already start scan")
                onBeaconScanListener.onScanErrorMsg("start scan already")
            } else {
                if (scanner == null) {
                    bleCallback = BeaconBleCallback(onBeaconScanListener)
                    adapter.startLeScan(bleCallback)
                } else {
                    // android 5.0
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        leCallback = BeaconLeCallback(onBeaconScanListener)
                        scanner?.startScan(leCallback)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun stopBeacon() {
            if (isScan) {
                // stop scan
                if (scanner == null) {
                    if (bleCallback != null) {
                        adapter.stopLeScan(bleCallback)
                    }
                } else {
                    if (leCallback != null) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            scanner?.stopScan(leCallback)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "already stop scan")
            }
        }
    }
```

ActivateBeacon.kt

```
class ActivateBeacon : AppCompatActivity(), OnBeaconScanListener {
    private lateinit var rippleView: RippleView

    override fun OnScanResult(beacon: Beacon) {
        Log.v("beacon", "result > $beacon")
        rippleView.newRipple()

    }

    override fun onScanErrorMsg(msg: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun getScanFilter(): BeaconFilter = BeaconFilter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ibeacon)
        rippleView = findViewById(R.id.circle_ripple)
        rippleView.newRipple()
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        IbeaconTooth.getIbeacon().startBeacon(this)

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        IbeaconTooth.getIbeacon().stopBeacon()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the snippet where you access this code section? Seems like you are not calling init before getIbeacon(). What you could do is to add a call to init inside the null check instead of throwing the error

Comment: This instance that you declare is in a companion object scope? Usually this context message that you got is only a warning because keeping a context statically may produce memory leak and bad behaviors in the app. The value being null, did you check if you really are setting any value in it? You're declaration define instance as null, therefore if you never change it...

Comment: Thanks-I added in the code section where it is accessed in the above

Comment: The second code you attached you are never calling init() and that was why the error was coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    companion object {

        var instance: IbeaconTooth? = null

        fun init(context: Context) {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(IbeaconTooth::class.java) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = IbeaconTooth(context)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun getIbeacon(context:Context): IbeaconTooth {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = init(context)
            }
            return instance as IbeaconTooth
        }

    }
```

This will eliminate the overhead of calling init before get.

Comment: thank you-I inputted this in but the init(context) doesn't seem to compile-what you put makes sense but not sure why it isnt working

Comment: @rengineer Sorry. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: yes I was able to figure out out-this worked. thank you